# Displaying an XML DataSource

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have an xml data file and I want to populate a listview in asp.net with this file. Can you show me how to generate an xslt and make a xml data file for this ?

Thanks

```
<Projects>
  <Project Name="" Category="" Subcategory="">
    <Subheader></Subheader>
    <Thumbnail></Thumbnail>
    <CreateDate></CreateDate>
    <Explanation></Explanation>
    <PdfFile></PdfFile>
    <WordFile></WordFile>
    <Subheader></Subheader>
    <SlideShow>
      <Image></Image>
<Image></Image>
    </SlideShow>
  </Project>
</Projects>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get started with transforming your XML with XSLT, there is a great tutorial [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp).

ASP.NET requires that you have some knowledge of that. Once you get that worked out, use the ASP.NET server control which simply joins the two files together and renders the HTML output. I recommend that you put the style tag in your XML file to start as you work out your XML. This is that syntax:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="somename.xsl"?>
```

Once you have that correct, add both files to the XML control.